# How to drawimage or clip my image to fit my control size

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, callback

I have 2 JavaScript pages. the first one has an image control and the second one has a function that returns a callback as an image.

page 1:

```
 //Calls the function from page 2 and the callback image is set as the source of the control.

previewImage(current, function(img) {
    jQuery(".mapItem").attr("src",img.src);
});
```

page 2:

```
//The functions callback returns an image which we use in page 1 (above)

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');

context.drawImage(this.m_Images[i],0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
var t = new Image();
t.src = canvas.toDataURL();
callback(t);
```

The issue:

my control in page 1 (.mapItem) has a height and width of 75.2px (fixed)
The image that is coming from the callback however will have a different size each time e.g one day it can be 200px * 300px and one day it can be 150px * 200px etc

How can i clip the image of the callback? I want the image (t) to zero (0) as x and y starting points and then clip the image where ever the .mapItem control height and width is.

I need this to be proportional ratio. So i cant just add the following code:

`context.drawImage(this.m_Images[i],0,0,72.5,72.5);` because this will ruin the image as we dont even know if it is square shaped.

What should i do?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I add a new solution please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to simulate your environment so here you have a possible solution.

1. `loadImage` is like your image loader that you have in your **Page 2**.
2. The load callback calls the `previewImage()` method.
3. This method receive the `img` extract the `width` and `height` calculate the aspect ratio with the `aspectRatioFit()` method.
4. And finally **draw the image** into the `mapItem` element in **Page 1**.

**Note**:

This is just a simulation based on your description try to adapt it your real project. If you have a question or you need an update of my solution. Please let me know.

**Update**:

If you want to Crop the image then just need to add `min-width` and `in-height` into the CSS style:

```
#mapItem {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}

#mapItem canvas {
    display: block;     // Otherwise it keeps some space around baseline
    min-width: 100%;    // Scale up to fill container width
    min-height: 100%;   // Scale up to fill container height
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; // Scaled images look a bit better in IE now
}
```

This will crop your image that you receive from the page 1.

```js
function loadImage() {
  var preview = document.getElementById('source_image');
  var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
    preview.src = e.target.result;
    preview.onload = function() {
      previewImage(this);
    };
  }, false);

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
};

function previewImage(img) {
  console.log(img.width + ' ' + img.height);
  var maxSize = {
    width: 75,
    height: 75
  };
  var croppedImage = document.getElementById('mapItem');
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx;
  //var newSize = aspectRatioFit(img.width, img.height, maxSize.width, maxSize.height);
  canvas.width = img.width;
  canvas.height = img.height;
  croppedImage.appendChild(canvas);
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function aspectRatioFit(srcWidth, srcHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight) {
  var ratio = Math.min(maxWidth / srcWidth, maxHeight / srcHeight);
  return {
    width: srcWidth * ratio,
    height: srcHeight * ratio
  };
}
```

```css
.clear {
  padding-bottom: 20%;
}

#mapItem {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
}

#mapItem canvas {
    display: block; /* Otherwise it keeps some space around baseline */
    min-width: 100%;    /* Scale up to fill container width */
    min-height: 100%;   /* Scale up to fill container height */
    -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; /* Scaled images look a bit better in IE now */
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="loadImage()"><br>
<div>
  <h3>Image in Page 2</h3>
  <img id="source_image" alt="Image preview..." />
</div>
<div>
  <h3>Image In page 1</h3>
  <div id="mapItem">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clear">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this works. however, my context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); doesnt work anymore after adding this functionality.

Comment: @sarah333 if you can show me your code I will provide a solution. If this was the answer to your original question please mark as answered to close the question. If you have integration problems I will help you also.

Comment: before i mark it, will this calculation work regardless of if height is greater than width or width greater than height? portrait and landscape? @Teocci

Comment: Yes, `aspectRatioFit()` method is in charge to calculate the dimensions of the image based on the original image and the destination

Comment: Also, could you please give an explanation of what exactly aspectRatioFit does. just so i know we are on the same page. thank you. @Teocci

Comment: I loaded an image with a height of 500px and width of 1000px and it loaded fine. however if my control is always 75 *75 i want it to always occupy the space within that. so the image should fill in this 75 *75 space. is this possible? is there a way to start at x and y 0 and cut the image off when it reaches 75 8 75?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142571/discussion-between-teocci-and-sarah333).